# Android Edit Text - Input Type Number not setting max value

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, numbers, android-inputtype

So what I would like is a very simple edit text with input type number or decimal that has the following aspects.

**Number Edit Text:**
You can only type up to `Long.MAX_VALUE` / `Long.MIN_VALUE`, so I can cast to a `long` without modifying the user's input.

**Number Decimal Edit Text:**
You can only type a number convertible to a `double`.

Also I do not need to use BigDecimal or BigIntegers, I need primitive values.
Finally, I know this was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825012/add-input-constraints-to-edit-text-in-android) but it is not what I want. There are some different requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it with a custom class extending `EditText` that adds a `TextWatcher` in the constructor. In the `afterTextChanged` method it tries to convert that to a long. If it fails (`NumberFormatException`) it sets the number to the respective min / max value (based on the "-" sign at the beggining of the number).